# Word or phrase describes place where I find people of similar taste or personality

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a single word of a phrase that describes a place (could be metaphoric or fantasy) where I meet people who have similar taste and/or personality like mine.

For example, a place where I find people who have the same taste as mine about movies, book, or food selections. I think such a place does not exist in real. Hence, I wonder if it exists, what would be the proper name for it?

I thought of `My Club`, but I wonder if there is more accurate word.

Comment: For me, that place would be EL&U!

Comment: like-minded people on the same page

Answer (score 1):

In English, a place like you described in your post is generally referred to as [a social club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_club). What kind of club it is specifically depends on what type of activity people do there. The Wikipedia article lists the names for the most common ones:

- anime club
- book discussion club
- charity work club
- chess club
- country club

Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

[Haunt](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/haunt) might do the trick for you.

Then again, of course, it might not.

Defined as *a place frequented by a specified person*:

*"The bar was a favourite haunt of artists of the time".*